# How is acceleration computed in the leap-frog algorithm in computer simulations of particles?

Tags: simulations, computational-physics

I am reading the book [*Computer Simulation of Liquids* by Allen and Tildesley](http://books.google.com/books/about/Computer_Simulation_of_Liquids.html?id=O32VXB9e5P4C) ([here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0198556454) is another link).  On page 80, the authors describe the leap-frog algorithm, which is used extensively in molecular dynamics (MD) simulations.  The leap-frog algorithm is a modification to the basic Verlet algorithm.  The authors state:

> Modifications to the basic Verlet scheme have been proposed to tackle [the deficiencies of the basic Verlet scheme].  One of these is a so-called half-step 'leap-frog' scheme.  The origin of the name becomes apparent when we write the algorithm down:
>
> $$\textbf{r}(t + \delta t) = \textbf{r}(t) + \textbf{v}(t + \frac{1}{2} \delta t) \delta t  \; \; \; \; \textbf{(3.17a)}$$
>
> $$\textbf{v}(t + \frac{1}{2} \delta t) = \textbf{v}(t - \frac{1}{2} \delta t) + \textbf{a}(t) \delta t \; \; \; \; \textbf{(3.17b)}$$
>
> The stored quantities are the current positions $\textbf{r}(t)$ and accelerations $\textbf{a}(t)$ together with the mid-step velocities $\textbf{v}(t - \frac{1}{2} \delta t)$.  The velocity equation **(3.17b)** is implemented first, and the velocities leap over the coordinates to give the next mid-step values $\textbf{v}(t + \frac{1}{2} \delta t)$.  During this step, the current velocities may be calculated:
>
> $$\textbf{v}(t) = \frac{1}{2} \left[ \textbf{v}(t + \frac{1}{2} \delta t) + \textbf{v}(t - \frac{1}{2} \delta t) \right]  \; \; \; \; \textbf{(3.18)}$$
>
> This is necessary so that the energy ($\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{K} + \mathcal{V}$) at time $t$ can be calculated, as well as any other quantities that require positions and velocities at the same instant.  Following this, equation **(3.17a)** is used to propel the positions once more ahead of the velocities.  After this, the new accelerations may be evaluated ready for the next step.  This is illustrated in Fig. 3.2.

[image: Leap-frog]

I have pasted Fig. 3.2 above; panel (b), framed in red, refers to the leap-frog algorithm.

My question is, how is the acceleration computed in this algorithm?

In Fig. 3.2(b), it appears that the first step (which I have personally highlighted in yellow) is to somehow compute $\textbf{a}(t)$ from $\textbf{r}(t)$.  However, I do not see an equation for this.  Do you know what equation the step highlighted in yellow would be?  Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The acceleration ${\bf a}(t)$ is simply computed from Newton law $F = m a $. It's a function of the forces on the particle, which is (assumedly) computable from the positions ${\bf r}(t)$ (of the entire system, i.e. all particles) at time $t$.

This can be seen also in the figures, in the three schemes the acceleration is computed from (and only from) the positions in that instant of time.