# Applying velocity Verlet algorithm

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, integrals-of-motion, algorithms, discrete

I want to implement a simple particules system using the [velocity form of the Verlet algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verlet_integration#Velocity_Verlet) as integrator.

Initial conditions at $t=0$ for a given particule $p$:

- mass: $ m $
- position: $\overrightarrow x(t=0) = \overrightarrow x_0$
- velocity: $\overrightarrow v(t=0) = \overrightarrow v_0$
- forces applied to it: $ \overrightarrow F(t=0) = \overrightarrow F_0 $

Algorithm's recipe says:

1. Calculate: $\overrightarrow v(t+\frac{1}{2}\Delta t) = \overrightarrow v(t) + \frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow a(t)\Delta t$
2. Calculate: $\overrightarrow x(t+\Delta t) = \overrightarrow x(t) + \overrightarrow v(t+\frac{1}{2}\Delta t) \Delta t$
3. Derive: $\overrightarrow a(t+\Delta t)$ from the interaction potential using $\overrightarrow x(t+\Delta t)$
4. Calculate: $\overrightarrow v(t+\Delta t) = \overrightarrow v(t + \frac{1}{2}\Delta t) + \frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow a(t+\Delta t)\Delta t$

---

Let's apply it in order to find $\overrightarrow x(t=1)$ and $\overrightarrow v(t=1)$, so with  $\Delta t = 1$:

1. $\overrightarrow v(0+\frac{1}{2}1) = \overrightarrow v(0) + \frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow a(0)1 = \overrightarrow v_0 + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\overrightarrow F_0}{m}$ [OK using Newton's second law]
2. $\overrightarrow x(0+1) = \overrightarrow x(0) + \overrightarrow v(0+\frac{1}{2}1) 1 = \overrightarrow x_0 + (1.)$ [OK using previous result *(1.)*]
3. **???**
4. $\overrightarrow v(0+1) = \overrightarrow v(0 + \frac{1}{2}1) + \frac{1}{2}\overrightarrow a(0+1)1 = (1.) + \frac{1}{2}(3.)$ [OK using *(1.)* and *(3.)*]

--

**So I'm stuck with *(3.)***

I have to calculate $\overrightarrow a(0+1)$ but I don't know how...
I can't apply Newton's second law here since I don't know $\overrightarrow F(t=1)$.
Algorithm says "from the interaction potential using *(1.)*" but I don't understand what it means...

Can you help?

Thank you

Comment: related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33751/how-is-acceleration-computed-in-the-leap-frog-algorithm-in-computer-simulations

Answer (score 2):

I think you all your steps are correct, I would suggest adding units though, otherwise adding $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{v}$ can be misleading.

For step 3. You can just calculate $a = F/m$, where $F$ can either be gravitation $F=m g$, so it does not depend on $x$, or for example for a spring dependent on $x$, so $F = -k x$, here you need the next position from step 2.

Comment: For step 3., I'm at $t=0$ and I'm calculating $\overrightarrow a(t+1)$ eg $\overrightarrow a(1)$. I only know $\overrightarrow F_{t=0}$ not $\overrightarrow F_{t=1}$ so like I was saying, I can't apply Newton's second law $\overrightarrow a(1) = \overrightarrow F_1/m$ since I don't have $\overrightarrow F_1$...

Comment: It depends on your potential, so as an example for a spring $F(1) = -k x(1)$, which you can use to calculate $a(1)$. The next position $x(1)$ comes from your second step.

Comment: But what if I can't have $F(1)$ for example in my case $F(t)$ depends on a user's interaction, eg: drag with mouse — so I cannot predict $F(1)$ when at $t = 0$ It's not a spring, or maybe it could be, but dragged by a crazy user with a mouse in his hand so I cannot have $k$ in advance.

Comment: @abernier: You always need to know the conditions beforehand, so I think there is no way your simulation lags 1 frame behind the user input. Maybe our game development partner site has more input on this.